# Using Regex to extract table names from a file containing SQL queries

Tags: c#, regex

I've a text file containing large number of queries. I want to get all the distinct tables used in the entire file in all the queries. The table name can come after a 'from' or 'join'. How can i extract them by doing a regex match. Can anyone suggest a regular expression to get the matches?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on structure of your file. Try to use this:

```
(?<=from|join)(\s+\w+\b)
```

Also turn on options Multiline if your not split your file in array or smth else with  singleline string members.
Also try to turn on IgnorCase option.

Comment: I think you have to move the \s+ into the positive lookbehind

Comment: -1 Regex is not the correct way to solve this problem. As tdammers states, a SQL parser of some description is required to effectively solve this problem.

Comment: @El Ronnoco I've asked for a solution using Regex and hence he has provided it. I just want a quick and dirty solution for this and i got it.

Comment: For support schema, i add few symbol: (?<=from|join)(\s+\w+\.+\w+\b)

Comment: I think it's not gonna work if there is a commented select in your string.

Comment: Actually there are a few edge cases on String functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

SUBSTR, SUBSTRING and TRIM can specify some parameters using FROM keyword, which has nothing to do with tables

Comment: you need to add INTO as this wouldn't work for insert statement

Answer (score 8):

I'd use:

```
r = new Regex("(from|join)\s+(?<table>\S+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

once you have the Match object "m", you'll have the table name with

```
m.Groups["table"].Value
```

example:

```
string line = @"select * from tb_name join tb_name2 ON a=b WHERE x=y";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(from|join)\s+(?<table>\S+)",
         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Compiled);

Match m = r.Match(line);
while (m.Success) {
   Console.WriteLine (m.Groups["table"].Value);
   m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

it will print:
tb_table
tb_table2

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
/(from|join)\s+(\w*\.)*(?<tablename>\w+)/
```

It won't match escaped table names though, and you need to make the regex evaluation case-insensitive.

Comment: Sorry. It is not even returning one match.

Comment: absolutely wrong. You can't find table names with such regex. You will match words join and from also. Not only table names.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it should match each occurrence of 'from' or 'join', followed by at least one whitespace, and then one or more identifiers separated with dots. There is one error though; it should start with a start-of-word assertion, otherwise it will also match things like `foobarfrom blah`. And it doesn't take escaping into account, because that's a DBMS-specific thing - MySQL uses backquotes, PostgreSQL uses double quotes, T-SQL uses square brackets.

Comment: Oh, and obviously, regexes are not a reliable way for doing this anyway. If you want reliable, you need a full-blown SQL parser.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions that can help you.

###### 1. Extract table names with alias from an SQL statement with Regex

Regular expression

```
/(from|join|into)\s+([`]\w+.*[`] *\w+|(\[)\w+.*(\]) *\w+|\w*\.*\w+ *\w+)/g
```

###### 2. Extract table names from an SQL statement with Regex

Regular expression

```
/(from|join|into)\s+([`]\w+.+\w+\s*[`]|(\[)\w+.+\w+\s*(\])|\w+\s*\.+\s*\w*|\w+\b)/g
```

Test string

```
-------------------------------------------------------
    select * into [dbo].[table_temp] 
    from [dbo].[table_a] a inner join dbo.table_b b ...
    join table_c c on ...
    from dbo.table_d d ...
    from `dbo`.`table_e` e ...
    from table_f f ...
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Generated Code for C#

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class QueryExtension
    {
        public static List<string> GetTables(this string query)
        {
            List<string> tables = new List<string>();
            string pattern = @"(from|join|into)\s+([`]\w+.+\w+\s*[`]|(\[)\w+.+\w+\s*(\])|\w+\s*\.+\s*\w*|\w+\b)";            
            
            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(query, pattern))
            {                
                string name = m.Groups[2].Value;                                
                tables.Add(name);
            }

            return tables;
        }
        public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator) {
            return string.Join(separator, values);
        }
    }
```

How to use it.

```
string input = @"select * into [dbo].[table_temp] 
from [dbo].[table_a] a inner join dbo.table_b b ...
join table_c c on ...
from dbo.table_d d ...
from `dbo`.`table_e` e ...
from table_f f ...";

Console.WriteLine(input.GetTables().Join("\n"));
```

Output

```
[dbo].[table_temp]
[dbo].[table_a]
dbo.table_b
table_c
dbo.table_d
`dbo`.`table_e`
table_f
```

###### Extract column names from an SQL statement with Regex

Regular expression

```
/(\w*\.*\w+|`\w*.*\w`|(\[)\w*.*(\]))+(,|\s+,|\s+FROM|\s+from)/g
```

Test string

```
-------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  
    [a].[column_1],  
    `b`.`column_2`,  
    c.column_3,  
    col4 as column_4,  
    col5 as `column_5`,   
    col6 as [column_6],
    column_7,
    a.col8 column_8,    
    (select max(column_x) from table_d where column_y in ('1','2','3')) as column_9    
from table_a a
inner join table_b b on ...
inner join table_c c on ...
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Generated code for C#

```
public static class QueryExtension
    {        
        public static List<string> GetColumns(this string query)
        {
            List<string> columns = new List<string>();
            string pattern = @"(\w*\.*\w+|`\w*.*\w`|(\[)\w*.*(\]))+(,|\s+,|\s+FROM|\s+from)";

            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(query, pattern))
            {
                string name = m.Groups[1].Value;
                columns.Add(name);
            }

            return columns;
        }
        public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator) {
            return string.Join(separator, values);
        }
    }
```

How to use it

```
string input1 = @"SELECT  
    [a].[column_1],  
    `b`.`column_2`,  
    c.column_3,  
    col4 as column_4,  
    col5 as `column_5`,   
    col6 as [column_6],
    column_7,
    a.col8 column_8,    
    (select max(column_x) from table_d where column_y in ('1','2','3')) as column_9    
from table_a a
inner join table_b b on ...
inner join table_c c on ...
";

 Console.WriteLine(input1.GetColumns().Join("\n"));
```

Output

```
[a].[column_1]
`b`.`column_2`
c.column_3
column_4
`column_5`
[column_6]
column_7
column_8
column_9
```

###### References

[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)
[Simplified Regular Expressions](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1499/controls-and-libraries/editors-and-simple-controls/common-editor-features-and-concepts/masks/mask-type-simplified-regular-expressions)
[Try regular expressions online](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I was looking for some ideas for myself, but I did not find them as expected, so I have to leave something. I hope you enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

can try this but it doesnt work for all the types of query,

```
  public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        string Line = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\ssis\queryfile.txt"))//reading the filename
        {

            var text = string.Empty;

            do
            {
                //     MessageBox.Show(Line);
                text = Line = sr.ReadToEnd();// storing it in a variable by reading till end

                MessageBox.Show(Line);



            } while ((Line = sr.ReadLine()) != null);



            var text1 = text.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty);//replacing brackets with empty space

            MessageBox.Show(text1);



            Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=from|join)\s+(?<table>\S+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);//regex for extracting the tablename after from and join

            Match m = r.Match(text1);//creating match object

            MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[1].Value);

            var v = string.Empty;



            while (m.Success)
            {

                v = m.Groups[0].Value;

                m = m.NextMatch();


                StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"D:\ssis\writefile.txt", true);// writing the match to the file

                var text2 = v.Replace(".", " ,"); // replace the . with , seperated values


                wr.WriteLine(text2);

                sr.Close();
                wr.Close();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(from|join)\s(\w+)
```

Comment: Nope. That will match either just "from" or "join table_name", but not "from table_name". The pipe splits the entire pattern, not just the first part.

Comment: Hmm. So can i wrap from|join with any parenthesis or something?