# Parsing specific keywords in Select Statements and formatting

Tags: python, bash

I have a sample select statement:

```
Select D.account_csn, D.account_key, D.industry_id, I.industry_group_nm, I.industry_segment_nm From ecs.DARN_INDUSTRY I JOIN ecs.DARN_ACCOUNT D
ON I.SRC_ID=D.INDUSTRY_ID
WHERE D.ACCOUNT_CSN='5070000240'
```

I would like to parse the select statements into separate files. The first file name is called ecs.DARN_INDUSTRY
and inside the file it should look like this:

```
industry_group_nm
industry_segment_nm
```

Similarly another file called ecs.DARN_ACCOUNT and the content looks like this:

```
account_csn
account_key
industry_id
```

How do I do this in Bash or Python??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you will find a truly simple answer (maybe someone can prove otherwise). However, you might find [python-sqlparse useful](https://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse/).

Parsing general SQL statments will be complicated and it is difficult to guess exactly what you are trying to accomplish. However, I think you are trying to extract the tables and corresponding column references via sql parsing, in which case, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483173/parsing-sql-query-and-pull-out-column-name-and-table-name) which basically asks that very thing directly.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you for showing me this module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a long working command through awk,

```
awk 'NR==1{gsub(/^.*\./,"",$5);gsub(/^.*\./,"",$6);gsub(/.$/,"",$5); printf $5"\n"$6"\n" > "DARN_INDUSTRY"; gsub(/^.*\./,"",$2);gsub(/^.*\./,"",$3);gsub(/^.*\./,"",$4);gsub(/.$/,"",$2);gsub(/.$/,"",$3);gsub(/.$/,"",$4); printf $2"\n"$3"\n"$4"\n" > "DARN_ACCOUNT"}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `gsub(/^.*\./,"",$5)` remove all the characters upto the first `.` symbol in colum number 5.
- `printf $5"\n"$6"\n" > "DARN_INDUSTRY"` redirects the output of `printf` command to the file named `DARN_INDUSTRY`.
- `gsub(/.$/,"",$4)` Removes the last character in column 4.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But this solution looks like it works for a specific scenario. I may have other tables which may be difficult to differentiate. Just by column numbers. I was hoping on getting a script that can dynamically generate the files by regex and some pattern matching criterias