# C# Get base table name along with alias or correlation name from a query

Tags: c#, sql, alias, correlation, getschematable

I am trying to parse a SQL query using:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

I get base table names, but I also need to find the table alias names.

Example Query:

```
select AuthorId, a.Name as [AuthorName], c.Name as City, s.Name as [State] from Author a
inner join Zipcode zc on zc.ZipCodeId = a.ZipCodeId
inner join City c on c.CityId = zc.CityId
inner join [State] s on s.StateId = c.StateId
```

I have checked [regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214045/using-regex-to-extract-table-names-from-a-file-containing-sql-queries), but not able to figure out how to extract "Author a", "ZipCode cd", "City c", "[State] s"

Comment: Changing thoughts here, I am taking a different route, got idea from here http://www.andriescu.nl/sql/sql-how-to-parse-microsoft-transact-sql-statements-in-c_sharp_view_column_binding/

Comment: And here is my project https://github.com/eyedia/aarbac

Answer (score 0):

Definitions that you must take into account to work with Regex type syntax.

###### Metacharacters

Metacharacters specify characters users can enter at the corresponding positions.

| Character | Descriptión |
| --- | --- |
| `.` | Any single character. |
| `[aeiou]` | Any single character from the specified character set. |
| `[^aeiou]` | Any single character not from the specified character set. |
| `[0-9a-fA-F]` | Any single character from the specified character range. |
| `\w` | Any single alphanumeric character. The same as `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` |
| `\W` | Any single non-alphanumeric character. The same as `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]` |
| `\d` | Any single numeric character. The same as `[0-9]` |
| `\D` | Any single non-numeric character. The same as `[^0-9]` |

###### Quantifiers

Quantifiers follow a metacharacter and specify how many times the character should be repeated. The table below lists the available qualifiers.

| Quantifier | Description | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `*` | Zero or more matches. The same as `{0,}` | `[a-zA-Z]`, `\w` |
| `+` | One or more matches. The same as `{1,}` | `[a-zA-Z]+`, `\w+` |
| `?` | Zero or one matches. The same as `{0,1}` | `[a-zA-Z]?`, `\w?` |
| `{n}` | Exactly n matches. | `[0-9]{2}` |
| `{n,}` | At least n matches. | `[0-9]{2,}` |
| `{n,m}` | At least n, but not more than m matches. | `[0-9]{2,7}` |

---

Solutions that can be of help.

###### 1. Extract table names from an SQL statement with Regex

Regular expression

```
/(from|join|into)\s+([`]*\w*.*\w[`]|(\[)*\w*.*(\])|\w*\.*\w*)/g
```

###### 2. Extract table names with alias from an SQL statement with Regex

Regular expression

```
(from|join|into)\s+([`]*\w*.*\w[`] *\w*|(\[)*\w*.*(\]) *\w*|\w*\.*\w* *\w*)
```

###### 3. Extract column names from an SQL statement with Regex

Regular expression

```
/(\w*\.*\w+|`\w*.*\w`|(\[)\w*.*(\]))+(,|\s+,|\s+FROM|\s+from)/g
```

Generated Code for C#

```
public static class QueryExtension
    {
        public static List<string> GetTables(this string query)
        {
            List<string> tables = new List<string>();
            string pattern = @"(from|join|into)\s+([`]*\w*.*\w[`]|(\[)*\w*.*(\])|\w*\.*\w*)";            
            
            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(query, pattern))
            {                
                string name = m.Groups[2].Value;                                
                tables.Add(name);
            }

            return tables;
        }
        public static List<string> GetTablesWithAliases(this string query)
        {
            List<string> tables = new List<string>();
            string pattern = @"(from|join|into)\s+([`]*\w*.*\w[`] *\w*|(\[)*\w*.*(\]) *\w*|\w*\.*\w* *\w*)";

            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(query, pattern))
            {
                string name = m.Groups[2].Value;
                tables.Add(name);
            }

            return tables;
        }
        public static List<string> GetColumns(this string query)
        {
            List<string> columns = new List<string>();
            string pattern = @"(\w*\.*\w+|`\w*.*\w`|(\[)\w*.*(\]))+(,|\s+,|\s+FROM|\s+from)";

            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(query, pattern))
            {
                string name = m.Groups[1].Value;
                columns.Add(name);
            }

            return columns;
        }
        public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator) {
            return string.Join(separator, values);
        }
    }
```

Test string

```
-------------------------------------------------------
select AuthorId, a.Name as [AuthorName], c.Name as City, s.Name as [State] from Author a
inner join `dbo`.`otherTable` ot on ot.col1 = a.Name
inner join Zipcode zc on zc.ZipCodeId = a.ZipCodeId
inner join City c on c.CityId = zc.CityId
inner join [State] s on s.StateId = c.StateId
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Output

```
//-------GetTables------
Author
`dbo`.`otherTable`
Zipcode
City
[State]
//-------GetTablesWithAliases------
Author a
`dbo`.`otherTable` ot
Zipcode zc
City c
[State] s
```

More code sample for C# (Here)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68889908/16731336

###### References

[Extract table names from an SQL statement with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68889908/16731336)
[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)
[Simplified Regular Expressions](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1499/controls-and-libraries/editors-and-simple-controls/common-editor-features-and-concepts/masks/mask-type-simplified-regular-expressions)